# Include additional files (DLLs or others) in Flutter Desktop release build

Tags: windows, flutter, build, command-line-interface

When building the release version of a Windows app using Flutter via CLI:

```
flutter build windows
```

I need to include a couple of files, like sqlite3.dll, in output folder, so I don't forget to package DLL dependencies or some readymade databases.

How can I do this automatically, so **flutter build** command copies files?

Comment: hi did you find the solution?

Comment: Excellent guide here: https://medium.com/flutter-community/build-and-deploy-native-c-libraries-with-flutter-cc7531d590b5